# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Raspberry Pi breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  7         13
Users destroyed                                  24          0
Users deleted                                     9          0
Users contacted                                  15          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue         1,087      1,035
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue              112        170
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue        603        752
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue              212      1,026
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                98      5,226
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              806      3,871
Tags merged                                       7          0
Tag synonyms proposed                            12          0
Tag synonyms created                              7          0
Tag highlight language set                        2          0
Revisions redacted                                4          0
Questions reopened                               88          0
Questions protected                              45         43
Questions migrated                               27          0
Questions flagged⁴                                4        959
Questions closed                              1,190        283
Question flags handled⁴                         276        687
Posts unlocked                                    1          4
Posts undeleted                                  11         70
Posts locked                                      0         52
Posts deleted⁵                                1,130      3,076
Posts bumped                                      0      8,722
Escalations to the CM team                        1          0
Comments undeleted                                9          0
Comments flagged                                  3        614
Comments deleted⁶                             1,048      2,013
Comment flags handled                           236        381
Answers flagged                                   5      1,885
Answer flags handled                          1,692        198
All comments on a post moved to chat             23          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: And a happy new year to you too, the whole CM team of SE, and to all our users.